# Adding text to each states in Map

Tags: javascript, svg

I have the maps**(jsfiddle)** which show the list of states in US **with name**, is there a possibility to add state code on each state. I tried to add a `text`, but it's not perfectly aligned in center of each states.

Below is the function which i am using to add in each states:

```
function addText(p){
    var t = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
    var b = p.getBBox();
    t.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + (b.x + b.width/2) + " " + (b.y + b.height/2) + ")");
    t.textContent = p.id;
    t.setAttribute("fill", "red");
    t.setAttribute("font-size", "14");
    p.parentNode.insertBefore(t, p.nextSibling);
}

var paths = document.querySelectorAll("path");
for (var p in paths)
{
    addText(paths[p])
}
```

Below is the JSFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/3sfou5bh/

Comment: See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60875994/7394871). Information about each state can be displayed using the `<title>` tags

Comment: But i don't want to display it in tooltip instead of i want the state code to be displayed inside the svg in center.